# How can I remove all attributes of for example of td element in one go?

Tags: dreamweaver

How can I remove all attributes of for example td element in one go?
I can use find/replace using tag and "remove attribute" one at a time. But I want to remove all attributes for any element.
Is there any such option in Dreamweaver CS4?

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following in the Find and Replace dialog:
Find:

```
<td[^>]*?>
```

replace

Check the "Use regular expression" box. Do a Find all first to ensure that you're finding only what you want to find.

Note: This assumes that you don't have any ">" characters within the opening TD tag. That could happen if you happen to have inline JavaScript such as:

```
<td onclick="if(x>y){alert('hi!');}">
```

But if you do, then you can do your replacement again and that should get the rest of the code in the opening of the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this.

FIND

```
<td( .*)">
```

REPLACE

```
<td>
```